# WFA DataGridView Load from Another Form

Tags: c#

I have a windows form with DataGridView (Form: DataGridForm) on it and a button for an advanced search which opens a new windows form (SearchForm) with the options of search:

1. ComboBox1 - Name, Lastname, Age, etc...
2. Combo Box2 - Equals, Does not equal, Contains, etc...

Based on the selected items of the ComboBoxes either a textbox or datetimepicker control is displayed.

For each selected option, there is a particular TableAdapter query method invoking. For example, if there are selected Name (ComboBox1) and Equals (ComboBox2), the textbox control is displayed which should pass an input to the query method - FillBy_EqualsName().

So, the problem is to load a result of the search to the DataGridView which is displayed on another windows form. For this, I'm using a piece of code in the button_click (Form: SearchForm) event but it does not work

Forms.DataGridForm dataGridForm = new Forms.DataGridForm();          dataGridForm.user_TableTableAdapter.FillBy_CotainsName(dataGridForm.userGridDataSet.User_Table, this.search_textbox.text);

What am I doin wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You create a new instance of DataGridForm but if I got you correctly you need to search in your exists DataGridForm. In this case you need to pass the data from SearchForm to your exists DataGridForm and do this with not a new instance of DataGridForm but with exists DataGridForm